# Как сделать прокрутку на сайте до конца и до определенного места? У меня не выходит?

Tags: python, playwright

```
            for (index, elem) in enumerate(list_of_categories):
                async with async_playwright() as p:
                    url = elem
                    browser = await p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
                    page = await browser.new_page()
                    await page.goto(url)
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    await page.click(".pointer.help-city__btn.btn.btn-large.btn-primary")
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    while True:
                        while await page.locator("button", has_text='Показать все').is_visible() is False:
                            await page.keyboard.down('End')
                            await page.click('mt-30.btn-pager')
```

Answer (score 0):

Документация говорит [`scrollIntoViewIfNeeded`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-scroll-into-view-if-needed).

```
btn = await page.locator("button", has_text='Показать все')
await btn.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
```